# vb.net allowing blank parameters

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

Hi I have the following SQL command on a form

```
INSERT Into response ([incident id],[response date],[response],[user cc 1],[user cc 2],[user cc 3],[reminder date],[follow up],[complete]) Values ([@incident id],[@response date],[@response],[@user cc 1],[@user cc 2],[@user cc 3],[@reminder date],[@follow up],[@complete])
```

The parameters for each are below

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@incident id]", txt_incidentid.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@response date]", dtp_responsedate.Value)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@response]", txt_response.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@user cc 1]", cb_usercc1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@user cc 2]", cb_usercc2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@user cc 3]", cb_usercc3.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@reminder date]", dtp_reminderdate.Value)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@follow up]", txt_followup.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@complete]", cb_complete.Text)
```

This currently works if every field is filled in otherwise the form crashes, However the following parameters don't always require a value

```
[@user cc 2],
[@user cc 3],
[@follow up]
```

How do I tell the SQL to ignore these parameters if the parameter is null?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

in database allow null , 
if you are using sp , set parameter default value to null

Comment: Sorry, should have added user cc 2 and user cc 3 are foreign keys linked to another table, access wont let me bypass those without an entry

Comment: @Boneyt - Your comment contradicts your original post.  In your post, you said _the following parameters don't always require a value_ but in your comment above, you say _access won't let me bypass those_!!   Which is it?  If the columns in Access don't allow NULLs than you _must_ pass in a value for the parameters.

Comment: Yes, I realised this shortly after and removed the FK links in the database to solve the issue. Thanks